# How do i disable the editing of a UITextView based on a UISwitch?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitextview, uiswitch

I have a UITextView and i want to disable it's 'editable' property if the state of the UISwitch is set to ON.

```
myTextView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 180, 200, 30)];
myTextView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
myTextView.text = @"This is a textView";
[self.view addSubview:myTextView];
mySwitch = [[UISwitch alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(230, 125, 200, 30)];
[self.view addSubview:mySwitch];
```

I know that i can check the state of a switch using:

```
if ([mySwitch isOn]) {
    myTextView.editable = NO;
} else {
    myTextView.editable = YES;
}
```

The problem is when i run my project the text is not editable, but when i slide the switch the text cannot be edited (which is obvious with above code). I want to know what do i have to do to change the editable property of the UITextView, if i toggle the switch.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an IBAction and hook it up to the switch method `Value Changed`

```
-(IBAction)toggleSwitch:(UISwitch*)sw {
    myTextView.editable = sw.on;
    NSLog(@"Value Changed");
}
```

Edit: Code for doing it programmatically rather than via Interface Builder

```
myTextView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 180, 200, 30)];
myTextView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
myTextView.editable = NO;
myTextView.text = @"This is a textView";
[self.view addSubview:myTextView];


mySwitch = [[UISwitch alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(230, 125, 200, 30)];
mySwitch.on = NO;
[mySwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(toggleSwitch:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.view addSubview:mySwitch];

-(void)toggleSwitch:(UISwitch*)sw {
    myTextView.editable = sw.on;
}
```

Comment: @Tejas K Is everything hooked up correctly in your storyboard?

Comment: Yes, i checked everything and looks fine.

Comment: I have tested the above code and it works, add a log into the function to make sure it is being fired.

Answer (score 1):

[`UISwitch`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISwitch_Class/) is a subclass of the [`UIControl`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/) class, which among other things, provides a target-action-based model for receiving updates about the state of the control.

This means that you can use the `-[UIControl addTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents]` method to have your method called when the switch changes its boolean value:

```
[yourSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchToggled:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged]
```

You can also do this from Interface Builder, by right-clicking on your `UISwitch` and assigning its `action` to the appropriate `IBAction` method:

```
- (IBAction) switchToggled:(UISwitch*)switchControl {
    yourTextView.editable = switchControl.on;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an action for the switch which fires when the switch's state has changed. If you are using storyboard, right-drag from the switch to the code (like to create an outlet) and choose `action`. Inside that function you check whether your switch is now on or off and according to that you make your TextView editable or not

Comment: I did what you suggested and now the initial state of the switch is ON and the text cannot be edited, i turn the swich OFF and then i can edit it, however when i turn the switch back ON, the text is still editable.

Comment: `- (IBAction)flipped:(id)sender {
    if ([mySwitch isOn]) {
        myTextView.editable = NO;
        
    } else {
        myTextView.editable = YES;
    
    }
}`

Comment: The above code is in .m file, sorry for the way it got posted, i am new here :)

Comment: @TejasK Place 2 breakpoints, 1 inside the `if` and 1 inside the `else` to check if at least that is working ok

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([mySwitch isOn]) {
    myTextView.editable = NO;
    [myTextView resignFirstResponder];
} else {
    myTextView.editable = YES;
    [myTextView becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: check your code and make sure there is no code like this: `myTextView .userInteractionEnabled = NO;`